# Script works in IE but not Chromium

Tags: javascript, chromium

I have a script I am using in a html file my program accesses. it has been using IE as the browser, but the new version no longer uses IE, it uses Chromium. some of the script works, but it gets to a point that it does nothing. no errors just stops. I am guessing there is a difference in the way Chromium handles the script. The script is one I got online and modified. I will include the code below. I use the update option the most "AutomateExcel3"  please ignore my code block outs and comments as I was trying to figure sometime else out.

thanks for the help

```
    <script>
       //*********************************************INTRODUCTION*****************************************
    //When using Web.Link the first thing to do is initialize what's called a handle to Pro/Engineer    
    // Get Session, Model.
    var mGlob = pfcCreate("MpfcCOMGlobal");
    var oSession = mGlob.GetProESession();
    var CurDwg = oSession.CurrentModel;
    var CurWind = oSession.CurrentWindow;

    var Base = "P:\ENGINEERING FILES\TPS PRE-PROD ENG\MV-22\excel_file.xls";

    function UpdateControls(Opt)
    {
    bottom.innerHTML = "";
    
    var Cntls="";
    if (Opt==1)
    {
        Cntls = "<H2>To Export:</H2>"+
                "<LI>Enter target Excel Files path</LI><LI>Pick \"Dwg Table\"</LI><LI>Pick Drawing Table</LI><P><INPUT id=FileName type=file size=80 value=\""+Base+"\"><BR>"+
                "<INPUT id=button1 type=button value=\"Dwg Table\" onclick=\"AutomateExcel1()\">";
    }
    else if (Opt==2)
    {
        Cntls = "<H2>To Import:</H2>"+
                "<LI>Enter the Excel Files path</LI><LI>Pick \"Next>>>\"</LI><LI>Pick Drawing To Place</LI><P><INPUT id=FileName type=file size=80 value=\""+Base+"\"><BR>"+
                "<INPUT id=button1 type=button value=\"Next>>>\" onclick=\"AutomateExcel2()\">";
    }
    else if (Opt ==3)
    {
        Cntls = "<H2>To Update:</H2>"+
                "<LI>Enter the Excel Files path</LI><LI>Pick \"Dwg Table\"</LI><LI>Pick Drawing Table</LI><P><INPUT id=FileName type=file size=80 value=\""+Base+"\"><BR>"+
                "<INPUT id=button1 type=button value=\"Dwg Table\" onclick=\"AutomateExcel3()\">";
            
                
    }

    middle.innerHTML = Cntls;

    }


    function AutomateExcel1()
    {
    var MultipleLinesInCells = false;
    
    //Have the user pick a table to export
    var SelOptions = pfcCreate("pfcSelectionOptions").Create  ("dwg_table");
    SelOptions.MaxNumSels = 1;
    var Selections = oSession.Select(SelOptions, null);
    
    var Table = Selections.Item(0).SelItem;
    
    //Build a matrix containing the values for the table
    var nTableRows = Table.GetRowCount();
    var nTableCols = Table.GetColumnCount();
    
    
    
    
    
    //Start a new Excel Spreadsheet
    var oXL;
    oXL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    var oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Add();
    var oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;
    
    
    //Loop around the table and dump information to excel
    for (i=0;i<nTableRows;i++)
    {
        for (j=0;j<nTableCols;j++)
        {
            var Cell = pfcCreate("pfcTableCell").Create(i+1, j+1);
            var Mode = pfcCreate("pfcParamMode").DWGTABLE_NORMAL;
            try
            {
                var Val = Table.GetText  (Cell,Mode);
                var Out="";
                if (Val.Count>1)
                    MultipleLinesInCells = true;
                    
                for (k=0;k<Val.Count;k++)
                {
                    if (k>0)
                    {
                        if (k<Val.Count)
                        {
                            Out = Out + " ";
                        }
                    }
                    Out = Out + Val.Item(k);
                
                }
                oSheet.Cells(i+1, j+1).Value = Out;
            }
            catch(er)
            {
                //Failure occurs when cells are merged, pro/e doesn't recognize cells that are now merged into another
            }
        }
    }
    
    //Bring up Excel for user to do with what they want.
    //oXL.Visible = true;
    oXL.UserControl = false;
    if (FileName.value==null)
        File = Base
    else
        File = FileName.value;
    try 
    {
        oWB.Close(true, File,null);
        oXL.Workbooks.Close();
        oXL.Quit();
        Base = FileName.value;
        var Out = "<H2>Success:</H2>Pick <a href=\""+File+"\">here</a> for created document";
        if (MultipleLinesInCells)
            Out = Out + "<H2>Warning:</H2>The export resulted in some Multi-line cells being concatenated";
        bottom.innerHTML = Out;
    }
    catch(er)
    {
        var Out = "<H2>Error:</H2>Could Not Write Specified File, please edit path and try again. If not Chuck Norris Might Get Angry!";
        bottom.innerHTML = Out;
    }
    
}


function AutomateExcel2()
{
    //Have the user pick somewhere
    var mousePick = oSession.UIGetNextMousePick  ( pfcCreate("pfcMouseButton").MOUSE_BTN_LEFT);
    var Orig = mousePick.Position;
    
    //Start Excel 
    var oXL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    try
    {
        var oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName.value);
        var oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;
        Base = FileName.value;
    }
    catch (er)
    {
        bottom.innerHTML = "<H2>Error:</H2>Could Not Open Specified File, \""+FileName.value+"\" for Import, please edit path and try again";
        return;
    }
    //Start the table instructions
    var TableInsts = pfcCreate("pfcTableCreateInstructions").Create  (Orig);
    
    var TableSizeType = pfcCreate("pfcTableSizeType").TABLESIZE_BY_NUM_CHARS;
    TableInsts.SizeType = TableSizeType;
    var columnInfo = pfcCreate ("pfcColumnCreateOptions");
    
    //Look for headers in top row
    var nCols=0;
    var Val = oSheet.Cells(1,nCols+1).Value;
    while (Val!=null)
    {
        nCols=nCols+1;
        Val = oSheet.Cells(1,nCols+1).Value;
        var column = pfcCreate ("pfcColumnCreateOption").Create (pfcCreate ("pfcColumnJustification").COL_JUSTIFY_LEFT,Math.round(oSheet.Cells(1,nCols).ColumnWidth+1));
        columnInfo.Append (column);
    }
    
    //Push column information into Table Instructions
    TableInsts.ColumnData = columnInfo;
    
    //Push in the Header row
    var rowInfo = pfcCreate ("realseq");
    rowInfo.Append (2.0); //title line
    TableInsts.RowHeights = rowInfo;
    
    //Now create the table in proe 
    var CurTable = CurDwg.CreateTable(TableInsts);
    
    //Populate the header information
    for (var i=1;i<=nCols;i++)
    {
        var Val = oSheet.Cells(1,i).Value;
        writeTextInCell (CurTable, 1, i, Val);
    }
    
    //Populate the rest of the table
    var i=2;
    var Row =  oSheet.Cells(i,1).Value;
    while (Row!=null)
    {
        CurTable.InsertRow   (1.0, i-1, false);
        
        for (var j=1;j<=nCols;j++)
        {
            var Val = oSheet.Cells(i,j).Value;
            writeTextInCell (CurTable, i, j, Val);
        }
        i=i+1;
        Row =  oSheet.Cells(i,1).Value;
    }
    
    
    
    
    //Close down Excel.
    oXL.UserControl = false;
    oWB.Close(true);
    oXL.Workbooks.Close();
    oXL.Quit();
    Excel.Application.Quit(); // added this to try to close excel
    
    var Out = "<H2>Success:</H2>Excel sheet imported as Pro/E Drawing Table";
    bottom.innerHTML = Out;
}

function AutomateExcel3()
{
    //Have the user pick a table to update
    var SelOptions = pfcCreate("pfcSelectionOptions").Create  ("dwg_table");
    SelOptions.MaxNumSels = 1;
    var Selections = oSession.Select(SelOptions, null);
    
    var Table = Selections.Item(0).SelItem;
        
    //Start Excel 
    var oXL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
    try
    {
        var oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName.value);
        var oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;
        Base = FileName.value;
    }
    catch(er)
    {
        bottom.innerHTML = "<H2>Error:</H2>Could Not Open Specified File, \""+FileName.value+"\" for Update, please edit path and try again.";
        return;
    }
    //Look for headers in top row and check them against the already existing headers
    var nProCols = Table.GetColumnCount  ();

    var nCols=0;
    var Val = oSheet.Cells(1,nCols+1).Value;
    while (Val!=null)
    {
        nCols=nCols+2;  // default was 1 changed to 2 now it doesn't delete the column if nothing in the first row.
        
        //Check to see if we need to add another column
        if (nCols>nProCols)
        {
            Table.InsertColumn   (Math.round(oSheet.Cells(1,nCols).ColumnWidth+1), nCols-1, false);
            nProCols=nProCols+1;
        }
        
        //Get current XL value
        var ValXL = oSheet.Cells(1,nCols).Value;
        
        //Get current ProE value
        var cell = pfcCreate ("pfcTableCell").Create (1, nCols);
        var mode = pfcCreate("pfcParamMode").DWGTABLE_NORMAL;
        try
        {
            var ValProE = Table.GetText  (cell, mode).Item(0);
            
        }
        catch(er)
        {
            var ValProE = "";
        }
        //Overwrite ProE value with XL value if they are not equal
        if (ValProE!=ValXL)
        {
            ModifyCellText(Table, cell, ValXL);
        }
        
        Val = oSheet.Cells(1,nCols+1).Value;
    }
    
//Check to see if any columns are left that need deleting off 
    //removed code and it appears to work without setting column to 15 above
      while (nCols<nProCols)
    {
        Table.DeleteColumn   (nProCols, false);
        nProCols=nProCols-1; //default was -1  (changed to -0 and crashed creo)
    }
    
    //Populate the rest of the table
    var nProRows = Table.GetRowCount();
    
    var nRows = 0;
    var Val = oSheet.Cells(nRows+1,1).Value;
    while (Val!=null)
    {
        nRows = nRows + 1;
        
        //Check to see if we need to add another row
        if (nRows>nProRows)
        { 
            Table.InsertRow  (1, nRows-1, false);
            nProRows=nProRows+1;
        }
        
        //Loop around all columns for each row
        for (i=1;i<=nCols;i++)
        {
            //Get current XL value
            var ValXL = oSheet.Cells(nRows,i).Value;
        
            //Get current ProE value
            var cell = pfcCreate ("pfcTableCell").Create (nRows, i);
            var mode = pfcCreate("pfcParamMode").DWGTABLE_NORMAL;
            
            try
            {
                var ValProE = Table.GetText  (cell, mode).Item(0);
            }
            catch(er)
            {
                var ValProE = "";
            }
            
            //Overwrite ProE value with XL value if they are not equal
            if (ValProE!=ValXL)
            {
                ModifyCellText(Table, cell, ValXL);
            }
        }
        Val = oSheet.Cells(nRows+1,1).Value;
    }
    
    //Check to see if any rows are left that need deleting off
    while (nRows<nProRows)
    {
        Table.DeleteRow  (nProRows, false);
        nProRows=nProRows-1;
    }
    
    CurDwg.Regenerate    ();
    
    
    //Close down Excel.
    oXL.DisplayAlerts = false;
    oXL.UserControl = false;
    oWB.Close(true);
    oXL.Workbooks.Close();
    oXL.Quit();
// below code seams to stop excel instance created by from task manager while leaving other instances of excel alone
    excel = null;
    excelfile = null;
    excelsheet = null;
    CollectGarbage();
    setTimeout("CollectGarbage()",1);
        oSheet = null;
        oWB = null;
        oXL = null;
    
// below code kills excel from taskmanager but all excel is closed.
var WshShell = new ActiveXObject("WScript.Shell");
var oExec = WshShell.Exec("taskkill /F /IM EXCEL.exe");
    
    CurDwg.UpdateTables  ();
    
    var Out = "<H2>Success:</H2>Excel sheet used as basis to update a Pro/E Drawing Table"+
                "<p>Note:"+
                "<LI>Cell Font and Alignment is Maintained for existing cells</LI>"+
                "<LI>Rows can be added and removed - this is likely to require extra formatting</LI>"+
                "<LI>There may be problems involving updating tables with merged cells</LI>"+
                "<LI>Ensure you check the table for correct format after an update</LI>"+
                "<LI>Congratulations Chuck Norris Approves!</LI>"+
                "</p>";
    bottom.innerHTML = Out;
}

function ModifyCellText(Table, cell, ValXL)
{
    try
    {
        var CellNote = Table.GetCellNote     (cell);
        var CellNoteInsts = CellNote.GetInstructions  (true);
        var CellNoteTextLines = CellNoteInsts.TextLines;
        var CellNoteTextLine1 = CellNoteInsts.TextLines.Item(0);
        var CellNoteTextLine1Texts = CellNoteTextLine1.Texts;
        var CellNoteTextLine1Text1 = CellNoteTextLine1Texts.Item(0);
    
        var FontName = CellNoteTextLine1Text1.FontName;
    }
    catch(er)
    {
        var FontName = "ariallight.TTF";
    }   
    var lines = pfcCreate("stringseq");
    lines.Append (ValXL);
    Table.SetText(cell, lines);
    
    var CellNote = Table.GetCellNote     (cell);

    var CellNoteInsts = CellNote.GetInstructions  (true);
    var CellNoteTextLines = CellNoteInsts.TextLines;
    var CellNoteTextLine1 = CellNoteInsts.TextLines.Item(0);
    var CellNoteTextLine1Texts = CellNoteTextLine1.Texts;
    var CellNoteTextLine1Text1 = CellNoteTextLine1Texts.Item(0);
    
    //Switch Font
    CellNoteTextLine1Text1.FontName = FontName;

    CellNote.Modify  (CellNoteInsts);
}


function writeTextInCell(table /* pfcTable */, row /* integer */,
                        col /* integer */, text /* string */)
 {
    var cell = pfcCreate ("pfcTableCell").Create (row, col);
    var lines = pfcCreate ("stringseq");
    lines.Append (text);
    
    try{
    table.SetText (cell, lines);
    }
    catch(er)
    {
        alert (row+"  "+col);
    }
 }
      
 
// Function to create the activeX objects that are the interface to Web.Link.
function pfcCreate (className)
{
  if (!pfcIsWindows())  
    netscape.security.PrivilegeManager.enablePrivilege("UniversalXPConnect");
  
  if (pfcIsWindows())
    return new ActiveXObject ("pfc."+className);
  else
    {
      ret = Components.classes ["@ptc.com/pfc/" + className + ";1"].createInstance();
      return ret;
    }
}

//Checks what OS is being operated
//IE11 requires more indepth browser testing...
function get_browser_info(){
    var ua=navigator.userAgent,tem,M=ua.match(/(opera|chrome|safari|firefox|msie|trident(?=\/))\/?\s*(\d+)/i) || []; 
    if(/trident/i.test(M[1])){
        tem=/\brv[ :]+(\d+)/g.exec(ua) || []; 
        return {name:'IE',version:(tem[1]||'')};
        }   
    if(M[1]==='Chrome'){
        tem=ua.match(/\bOPR\/(\d+)/)
        if(tem!=null)   {return {name:'Opera', version:tem[1]};}
        }   
    M=M[2]? [M[1], M[2]]: [navigator.appName, navigator.appVersion, '-?'];
    if((tem=ua.match(/version\/(\d+)/i))!=null) {M.splice(1,1,tem[1]);}
    return {
      name: M[0],
      version: M[1]
    };
 }
function pfcIsWindows ()
{
var browser = get_browser_info();

if (browser.name.indexOf ("IE") != -1)
 return true;
else
 return false;
}
</script>
```

code worked perfectly in IE but not in the new browser I am forced to use

Comment: ActiveXObject is obsolete

Comment: so all callouts to activeXobject need to be updated? what should they be now? thanks

Comment: PDF file, Google Docs, Office Online, other HTML + JS based document viewers, or download the files  to work separately from the browser.  Modern browsers do not allow embedding native code plugins like ActiveX, Java, Flash for security reasons.  The exception is Chrome and Edge (and others?) include a built-in PDF viewer plugin.

Comment: _“but it gets to a point that it does nothing. no errors just stops.”_ — Use the [browser console (dev tools)](//webmasters.stackexchange.com/q/8525) (hit `F12`), read any errors. You’ll see a very clear error indicating that `ActiveXObject` no longer exists. _“what should they be now?”_ — That’s easy to Google.

Comment: actually hitting f12 does nothing because this is all executing in a bowser that is running  in another program without access to things like that. that program (PTC Parametric) does need the ability to be able to launch local programs. ActiveX might not be the best way to do it anymore, but simply put it worked perfectly until PTC  made chromium the default browser with no way to change the browser

Comment: " — That’s easy to Google. " Maybe, but finding a work around for it isn't. A google search says use ActiveX digging through even more says it is impossible. I don't believe that. it is going to be a huge pain though if that is the problem (which it looks like) and there isn't a work around. my code I was using saved hours of work per file.

Comment: Modern browsers do not support ActiveX, period.  They can launch applications that run on their own outside of the browser, like how a web page can launch Zoom or Teams meeting, but that runs it completely detached.  The browser says "do you want to launch teams" and if you say OK then it can pass a command line to it then the connection ends.  That kind of launch must be set up in the registry by adding keys for the "mailto:" type URL prefix.  Chrome, Edge, Firefox,. etc. support this but your embedded browser might not.

Comment: Thx! I don't have an issue pressing ok each time . I just need to be able to do it in the browser if possible. I am accessing a .html file on my system to do all of this. so security isn't really an issue on this. I understand how it can be though. I am not sure but I think it is also getting stopped before the activeX code. in the part where I am supposed to select the table, before it would highlight it, then open excel in the background and do it's thing. now it doesn't show anything is selected when I click the table. might still just be the activeX though IDK. thx for the help

Comment: I made some progress. turns out it wasn't stopping at the activeX command to open excel, though that is still a problem. it was stopping at the browser check. since chromium wasn't one of the option, it stopped there. once I got that fixed, it now gets to the point of the activeX to launch excel. since I can't do that, I want to just read the .xlsx file I selected. I know there are sever ways for java to read an xlsx file. the problem I am having is telling it what to do.  I think this part of the code is the issue.

Comment: var oXL = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application"); <-- which i can't do and without that I can't do these. try
 {
  var oWB = oXL.Workbooks.Open(FileName.value);
  var oSheet = oWB.ActiveSheet;
  Base = FileName.value;
 }
 catch(er)
 {
  bottom.innerHTML = "<H2>Error:</H2>Could Not Open Specified File, \""+FileName.value+"\" for Update, please edit path and try again.";
  return;
 }
 
 I get the " for Update, please edit path and try again."
 
 What I think I need to do is something like this Var oXL = data read from .xlsx  but I don't know how to do that